# the app crashes when using OkHttpClient in doInBackground

Tags: java, android, okhttp

My application on Android LOLLIPOP runs well, but in the lower version, program crashe and displays this error:

> Exception caught 
>                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

And points to this line of code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
```

this is my code:

```
private void getMoviesFromDBz(int id) {

    AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... movieIds) {

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(linkkk + movieIds[0])
                    .build();
            try {
                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    Movie movie = new Movie(object.getInt("id") , object.getString("per") , object.getString("movie_name"),
                            object.getString("movie_image"), object.getString("movie_genre") , object.getString("movie_discription") , object.getString("movie_lat"), object.getString("movie_lon") , object.getString("movie_marker") , object.getString("sort") , object.getString("price") , object.getString("email") , object.getString("tell") , object.getString("location") , object.getString("count"));


                    ItemOneFragment.this.movies2.add(movie);
                }


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            getMoviesFromDB(0);
        }
    };

    asyncTask.execute(id);
    scroll2 = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access the Main/UI Thread in a background Thread:

`ItemOneFragment.this.movies2.add(movie);`

just return the `movie` object and execute the above line on the `onPostExecute()` method, also I wouldn't recommend instantiating an `OkHttpClient` for each request.

Comment: Yes this is also better way to solve this issue @Farshad.A

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to performing action the  on UI Thread from background Thread. So you can use`runonuithread`

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                         ItemOneFragment.this.movies2.add(movie);
                    }
                });
```

see the changes below in your code.

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... movieIds) {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(linkkk + movieIds[0])
                .build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                Movie movie = new Movie(object.getInt("id") , object.getString("per") , object.getString("movie_name"),
                        object.getString("movie_image"), object.getString("movie_genre") , object.getString("movie_discription") , object.getString("movie_lat"), object.getString("movie_lon") , object.getString("movie_marker") , object.getString("sort") , object.getString("price") , object.getString("email") , object.getString("tell") , object.getString("location") , object.getString("count"));


                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                         ItemOneFragment.this.movies2.add(movie);
                    }
                });
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I think this may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any Asynctask with Okhttp

Look up [examples that use the enqueue method](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/AsynchronousGet.java)

```
// Build the client and request in the main thread 

// Start an asynchronous method 
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

       JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseBody.string());
      }
    }
});
```

If you want to use JSON objects with Okhttp, Retrofit would be a better  library